# Akeneo PIM No alive nodes found in your cluster ERROR

Tags: elasticsearch, server, akeneo, pim, uberspace

I keep getting the same error when starting the Akeneo Community Edition! It seems to be an error caused by Elastictsearch, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

The Error message:

```
 [OK] Database schema created successfully!



 Updating database schema...

     37 queries were executed


 [OK] Database schema updated successfully!


Reset elasticsearch indexes

In StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php line 50:

  No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Im running on a uberspace server without docker and i'm trying to start it like mentioned here:
https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/install_pim/manual/installation_ee_archive.html but with the community Edition instead.

Does anyone had the same error and knows how to help me out?

Maybe it a problem with the .env file for the entry point of elastic search. My .env: `APP_INDEX_HOSTS=localhost:9200`

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the Elasticsearch search server is available on localhost:9200 when accessing it via curl/Postman/Sense or something else?

That error usually means the node is either not running, or not running on the configured port.

Pay also attention that your server follow the system requirements - https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_requirements.html

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem! Elasticsearch does not start on the Uberspace server. Also the Uberspace support could not help.